# Help finding a video Editor for Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: video

I have downloaded almost everything from the list.  OpenShot won't open.  Neither will FlowBlade.  KdenLive will open but it won't let me add any videos of any kind.  Nothing works on 22.04.  I am just a beginner with video editing.  Is there anything in the repo that works out of the box with 22.04?

I have ffmpeg and all of that stuff installed.  KdenLive just says "Cannot open file" for every file type I can think of.

When I tried to run openshot it would initially open and then throw an error about an unsupported floating point number and immediately close again.  I wasn't able to find a build that would run.

Please tell me that there is something in the repo that I can just use.

Comment: I have been using this recently https://www.shotcut.org/

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to use snap instead of apt to install KdenLive.  I uninstalled with apt and then reinstalled through snap and it started working.